# Sou obrigado a chamar um Parâmetro caso determine ele em uma funcao?

Tags: javascript

Ola estou com uma leve duvida tipo caso eu determine um Parâmetro na criação da funcao javascript sou obrigado a chamar ele ?
exemplo:

```
    function ts(metodo){
     //código aqui
   }
```

Posso da um onclick sem determinar aquele Parâmetro ? 
exemplo:

```
<span onclick="ts();"> ts </span>
```

Ou sou obrigado a chamar o Parâmetro junto?

E se não como faço para verificar se o Parâmetro foi enviado tipo o isset do php ?

Comment: Você tem uma função que recebe um parâmetro, mas não quer passar um parâmetro para a função? É isso? Se sim, dependerá do código que tem em "código aqui". Se a função não estiver tratada para não receber o parâmetro, não fará sentido chamá-la sem ele.

Comment: sim isso , n sabia que chamava de parametro rs. e tambem como faço para verificar se veio algum coisa no parametro tipo  se o parametro existe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não é obrigado a passá-lo, mas a função precisa estar tratada para o caso de o parâmetro não estiver definido, caso contrário não fará sentido fazê-lo.

Por exemplo, supomos uma função que exibe no console uma mensagem de saudação. A função receberá o nome a qual será saudado:

```js
function hello(name) {
  console.log(`Olá, ${name}`)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello('mandioca')">Saudar</button>
```

Mas, veja o que acontece quando você não define o parâmetro:

```js
function hello(name) {
  console.log(`Olá, ${name}`)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Saudar</button>
```

A função é executada, mas aparece um "undefined", pois o parâmetro não foi definido.

Neste caso, se realmente fazer sentido chamar a função assim, você pode atribuir um valor padrão quando não for definido o parâmetro:

```js
function hello(name) {
  name = name || 'mandioca'  // Se não tiver definido, atribui o valor 'mandioca'
  console.log(`Olá, ${name}`)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Saudar</button>
```

Assim, quando você chama a função sem um parâmetro, a função irá atribuir um valor padrão e continuar a execução.

Comment: e o modo tipo isset do PHP tipo if(isset($ts)) para o javascript?

Comment: @CyberHacker não entendi o que quis dizer

Comment: queria verificar se o parâmetro foi ou n passado caso foi ele execute uma parte da function caso n ele execulte outra parte

Comment: Pode user `typeof name === 'undefined'` para verificar quando não foi passado.

Comment: no PHP ia ser tipo:
 ` if(isset($var)){}else{} `

Comment: obrigado deu aqui